# Using a iOS UITabBar with MVVMCross MvxViewController not MvxTabBarViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

We have a 4 views that are considered siblings in the UX design and so we would like to display them on a TabBar in iOS. We already have them in a NavigationDrawer in Android.

Lets call them

1. Customer
2. CustomerOrders
3. CustomerHistory
4. Returns

These are represented by 4 separate ViewModels. Looking at the [MvxTabBarViewController samples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-25-Tabbed/Tabbed.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L35-43) I have to created a Uber ViewModel that exposes all 4 ViewModels as properties. Then attach the 4 views (MvxViewControllers) to a Parent View (MvxTabViewController).

**UPDATE**

<strike>I don't want to create a ViewModel just to support iOS' way of doing things.
I tried creating a UITabBar as a standalone view but that fails to deal with more than 5 items.</strike>

I have given up trying to fight the toolbar and am going to create a iOS specific ViewModel to host the Customer, CustomerOrders, CustomerHistory and Returns ViewModels. That is how the MvxTabViewController wants me to do it so I will. Getting that to work involves some MVVMCross configuration that I think is best handled by a new question. <strike>Once created I will link to it from here</strike> [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165092/hosting-and-initialising-multiple-mvvmcross-viewmodels-for-the-mvxtabviewcontrol)

Any suggestions?