# Hosting and initialising multiple MVVMCross ViewModels for the MvxTabViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I need to create a Tab view in iOS. I tried to do this by simply adding a UITabBar to an MvxViewController but I could not get that to work (See [this question if interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107355/using-a-ios-uitabbar-with-mvvmcross-mvxviewcontroller-not-mvxtabbarviewcontrolle))

I am now trying to go use the approach MVVMCross and Apple seem to push me towards, a TabController.

In our Core project we have 4 ViewModels that are displayed from one or more places using a ShowViewModel call and are initialised with a customerNumber.

1. CustomerViewModel
2. CustomerOrdersViewModel
3. CustomerHistoryViewModel
4. ReturnsViewModel

In Android and Windows Store we have separate Views for each of these ViewModels. I do not want to change our Core implementation to support iOS. I  will create a new ViewModel called `TabbedCustomerViewModel` and that will have 4 properties, one for each of the hosted ViewModels.

Using a custom MvxTouchViewPresenter registered in the iOS project I can listen for  requests to Show one of the Customer views and then switch the Request to `TabbedCustomerViewModel`. I have that working, the new ViewModel gets created and the initialisation paramaters that would have been passed to the original VM are passed to the intercepting VM's Init method.

The problem I am having is knowing how I should be initialising the hosted VMs. I assume I am going to have to ctor, init and Start them manually. Has anyone got any thoughts on how to do this?

The [N-25 Tab Tutorial](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-25-Tabbed/Tabbed.Core/ViewModels/FirstViewModel.cs) does not have to worry about this as its hosted VMs are not standalone so don't have Init and Start dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the initialisation of the VMs working now too. When the View loads it checks if it is within a Tabbed UI by looking at the ParentViewController.

If it is it calls a custom method on the new `TabbedCustomerViewModel`. I have copied the code that MVVMCross use and added it to the new Method

```
try
{
    mvxViewModel.CallBundleMethods("Init", this.initialisationParameters);
    if (reloadedState != null)
    {
        mvxViewModel.CallBundleMethods("ReloadState", reloadedState);
    }
    mvxViewModel.Start();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw exception.MvxWrap("Problem initialising viewModel of type {0}", mvxViewModel.GetType().Name);
}
```

The initialisationParameters and reloadedState are stored by `TabbedCustomerViewModel` when it is initialised so that it can pass it down to the ViewModels it is hosting